# Bad to Set slider.value When User has Changed Slider Position?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, infinite-loop, uislider

In the online [Stanford CS193p iPhone Application Development](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) course, lecture 6, an application is built which has a slider as input and a custom view as output.

**When the slider is changed, the view controller sets the slider value again.**

Important bits of the view controller in [Happiness 2.zip](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Happiness%202.zip):

```
@implementation HappinessViewController

@synthesize happiness;

- (void)updateUI
{
    // assignment-loop when called from happinessChanged:?
    self.slider.value = self.happiness; // sets slider to model's (corrected) value
    [self.faceView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setHappiness:(int)newHappiness
{
    if (newHappiness < 0) newHappiness = 0; // limit value
    if (newHappiness > 100) newHappiness = 100;
    happiness = newHappiness;
    [self updateUI]; // changed happiness should update view
}

- (IBAction)happinessChanged:(UISlider *)sender // called by changed slider
{
    self.happiness = sender.value; // calls setter setHappiness:
}
```

**Doesn't this result in a loop (slider changed -> model updated -> change slider -> ?)?**

**Or is this even good practice?**

Comment: Good question. The only clue I can find in the UISlider docs is: "If `NO`, the slider only sends an action event when the user releases the slider’s thumb control to set the final value."

Comment: That'd be the "continuous" property I guess? In the lecture this must be set to `YES` as the smily changes its smile _while_ the slider is dragged. I guess the problem would be the same but manifest differently - with `YES` and a non-fitting `slider.value` translation it would presumably be a jerky user interface + maybe an action loop, and with `NO` it would maybe just be the loop.

Comment: Yes, I know `continuous` is probably not related. I just mentioned it because it talks about *when* the action event will be sent. But I'm still not sure if this is guaranteed to work in general. This might be a good question on http://devforms.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks, [posted there](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/117794). Note that you misspelled your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the slider is updated from code, rather than by the user, it presumably doesn't sent the valueChanged action. So you don't get an infinite loop.

This can be used to "correct" the value selected by the user, or to force the slider onto regular tick marks instead of a smooth scale.

Comment: ok, i got the chance to check: setting the slider value does *not* trigger `Value Changed`.